# ajax received links unclickable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been messing around with ajax the last few days and I'm stuck when it comes to keep links clickable.

I have a menu with a few listitems and attached an eventhander in an external javascript file which looks like that:

```
document.getElementById('home').addEventListener("click", navigate, false);
```

for all elements. In the navigate function I am using the ajax:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/navigation.php",
        data: "clicked=" + this.id,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(response) {
            if (response && response.text1 && response.text2) {
                $("#leftContent").html(response.text1);
                $("#rightContent").html(response.text2);
            }
        }
    });
```

I am using the json datatype so I can seperate the data for two divs #leftContent and #rightContent. now the php file makes some simple queries to get data from a db.
however this works fine! the code filled into the html objects works. I'm styling it with css to make it look good and it seems like the solution above is ok.

BUT when I respond with a link in the navigation.php file it's not clickable.
so imagine the navigation.php looks like this (simplified)

```
$content = json_encode(array(
            'text1' => '<a href="127.0.0.1">link</a>"',
            'text2' => 'This text would go in response text 2'
        ));

echo $content;
```

I tried to just use href="#" and use the onlick method and use a function to handle this but still nothing happens. I did search the net and came across the bind()-method which allows to add and Eventhandler.
well I could this but what if I receive a list of links from the php file. some kind of:

```
$content = json_encode(array(
            'text1' => '<a href="http://...">link</a><br /> <a href="http://...">link</a><br /> <a href="http://...">link</a><br /> ',
            'text2' => 'This text would go in response text 2'
        ));

echo $content;
```

I can add an event handler to the whole list then but not each single element.
is there a simple solution?
Using multidimensional arrays as a response and parsing the data would be an idea. Or is there just a simple way to do this?

Comment: Can you show rendered HTML markup for anchor tag once ajax request is done? And what do you mean exactly by `BUT when i respond with a link in the navigation.php file it's not clickable`?  FYI, `async: false,` is deprecated and anyway there is no reason to use it

Comment: well just use ajax like above(u can even try it without the json array, just with one simple response text) and call a php script which simply returns a  link like 'code'(<a href>linke here</a>) and you will notice that u cannot click that link. also u cannot use css:hover or onClick-method for javascript.

Comment: **BUT** what do you mean by not clickable? If you mean any previously click handler isn't fired, then delegate event. If you mean the `href` attribute is ignored, then you need to provide minimalistic sample replicating your issue because your problem comes from somewhere i'm not aware of

Comment: so the link with the <a></a> tags surrounded is displayed like the default link (if you haven't modified it in css) but the href attribute is ignored. also the :hover property and any onClick handler is ignored! its simply treated like a normal <p></p> tag. consider the following html:
'code'(<a href="www.something.com" onClick="dosomething()">LINK</a>)
if this is the response of the php file  then the LINK is styled like a <a></a> BUT href is ignored and onClick doesnt start the doSomething() function!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery `on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind the container, allowing you to maintain your events while replacing the links:

Something like:

```
$('#leftContent').on('click', 'a', navigate);
```

Comment: The question isn't clear at all imho but i'm quite sure this is the anwser

Comment: do you also know why those tags lose those properties like clickabilty or :hover or the onClick method? since you respond with html tags the browser should actually notice that its a link, right? or is this because the DOM is already loaded and you dont force it to reload with the ajax request and so its displayed but properties are not usable?